# how to extract an integer range from a string

Tags: string, kotlin

I have a string that contains different ranges and I need to find their value

`var str = "some text x = 1..14, y = 2..4 some text"`
I used the `substringBefore()` and `substringAfter()` methodes to get the x and y but I can't find a way to get the values because the numbers could be one or two digits or even negative numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this solution fit for you?

```
val str = "some text x = 1..14, y = 2..4 some text"    
val result = str.replace(",", "").split(" ")
var x = ""; var y = ""

for (i in 0..result.count()-1) {
    if (result[i] == "x") {
        x = result[i+2]
    } else if (result[i] == "y") {
        y = result[i+2]
    }
}

println(x)
println(y)
```

Comment: This solution breaks as soon as you have some single "x" or "y" inside the text, e.g. "x = 1..14, y = 2..4 - as we can see the range for x is larger than the one for y" would lead to a value "larger" for `x`, if we would not have an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` since there is nothing 2 indices after the last occurrence of "y".

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to use a regex, e.g.:

```
val str = "some text x = 1..14, y = 2..4 some text"

val match = Regex("x = (-?\\d+[.][.]-?\\d+).* y = (-?\\d+[.][.]-?\\d+)")
            .find(str)
if (match != null)
    println("x=${match.groupValues[1]}, y=${match.groupValues[2]}")
    // prints: x=1..14, y=2..4
```

`\\d` matches a single digit, so `\\d+` matches one or more digits; `-?` matches an optional minus sign; `[.]` matches a dot; and `(`…`)` marks a group that you can then retrieve from the `groupValues` property. (`groupValues[0]` is the whole match, so the individual values start from index 1.)

You could easily add extra parens to pull out each number separately, instead of whole ranges.

(You may or may not find this as readable or maintainable as string-manipulation approaches…)

Answer (score 0):

Using KotlinSpirit library

```
val rangeParser = object : Grammar<IntRange>() {
    private var first: Int = -1
    private var last: Int = -1

    override val result: IntRange
        get() = first..last

    override fun defineRule(): Rule<*> {
        return int {
            first = it
        } + ".." + int {
            last = it
        }
    }
}.toRule().compile()

val str = "some text x = 1..14, y = 2..4 some text"
val ranges = rangeParser.findAll(str)
```

https://github.com/tiksem/KotlinSpirit